# NOINDEX,NOFOLLOW for selected category pages

Tags: category, magento-1.7, robots.txt

I'm reading [this](http://doejo.com/blog/magento-how-to-add-noindex-nofollow-robots-meta-tag-or-change-meta-title-or-description-on-certain-pages/#.U1_QYK1dWbQ), and it says that you can add `NOINDEX,NOFOLLOW` directives using page handles on files like `local.xml`. What I want to do is to include these directives for a certain selected set of category pages.

It also says you can do this in general under `layout updates` in CMS pages. I'm assuming the counter part in categories is the `custom layout update` under `Catalog` > `Categories` > `Custom Design tab`. So, I'm thinking I can put the following in the categories I selected.

```
<reference name="head">
   <action method="setRobots"><value>NOINDEX,FOLLOW</value></action>
</reference>
```

Is this correct for what I want to do?

I also see an option called `Page Layout` under which there are options like `No layout updates`, `1 column`, etc.. Does this need to be modified as well?

It looks like this works, but I want to confirm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically that's it.

I do something similar to change the type of banner rotator on some special category pages and the entries look like this.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, it seems to be working when I look at the source code on the pages.